# Google OpenID force prompt account to use

Tags: openid

I've implemented Google OpenID login for a website and its working well. If I'm logged in to Google and try to login from my website Google automatically uses the logged in account and redirects back to my website. This is good when I'm logged in to the right account. The problem is I have multiple Google Accounts and sometimes I'm logged in to the wrong one. When Google redirects me back my site is prompting to complete setting up a new account.

Is it possible to get Google to always ask which account to login with?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but according to Google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#prompt) you can use the  prompt parameter of the authentication URI with the 'select_account' value